# Weighted Average in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using imported GA data to calculate the average product position on a page, I am currently doing this by averaging the item position by SKU - is there a way to calculate this as a weighted average within my query, as a product could display 10 times in position 1, and once at position 10, I wouldn't want the average to be 5.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT hits.product.productSKU AS SKU, AVG(hits.product.productListPosition) AS Average_Position
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([***.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-04-24'), TIMESTAMP('2016-04-30')))
GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY Average_Position ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this query and it worked here:

```
SELECT
  sku,
  nom / den avg_position from(
  SELECT
    sku,
    SUM(position * freq) nom,
    SUM(freq) den from(
    SELECT
      prods.productsku sku,
      prods.productlistposition position,
      COUNT(prods.productlistposition) freq
    FROM
      `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`,
      UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
      UNNEST(hits.product) prods
    WHERE
      1 = 1
       AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-04-24') AND TIMESTAMP('2016-04-30')
      AND prods.productlistposition > 0
    GROUP BY
      sku,
      position )
  GROUP BY
    sku )
```

Notice that I used the [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) version of BigQuery as this is highly recommended.

If you must use the Legacy version adapting this query might be easy (supposing you don't have to use the `FLATTEN` operation).

You said you want to consider the positions on a given page, this can be done as well by inserting in the first `where` clause the condition

```
and hits.page.pagepath = 'your page url'
```